# I need help identifying why i cant query these $_get variables into sql

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$kundenr     = $_GET["kundenr"];
$kundenr   = mysql_real_escape_string($kundenr);
$kundenavn = $_GET["kundenavn"];
$kundenavn = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["kundenavn"]);

$servername = "random";        
$username = "random";          
$password = "random";          
$dbname = "random";               


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);     
if ($conn->connect_error) {                                         
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


$sql = "INSERT INTO customerbase (kundenr, kundenavn) VALUES('$kundenr','$kundenavn')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
echo "<br>" . $sql;
echo "<br>" . $kundenr;
echo "<br>" . $kundenavn;
} 
else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();     
?>
```

output of the above is as follows :

New record created successfully
INSERT INTO telefoncentral (kundenr, kundenavn) VALUES('','')

i cant for the love of god figure out why it wont put in the values

can anyone see the error? im going mildy crazy here

URL line it gets is new.php?kundenr=0236&kundenavn=Peter

Comment: You’re mixing functions/methods of the MySQL and MySQLi extensions. You can’t use both at the same time. I suggest using MySQLi with prepared statements.

Comment: what does   print_r( $_GET); results...

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string()` requires a `mysql_connect()` connection in order to work, since you're only contacting the database later in the script, no such connection will be available. You should only call this function in the place where you are inserting data.

Furthermore you're mixing the `mysql_` extension with the `mysqli_` extension, you'll want to use something like `$conn->escape_string()` in your code.

Ideally you should not use `real_escape_string` at all, but instead read up on what [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) are.